# Moore-Penrose inverse multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I really need help proving that when $AB=0$ then $B^+A^+=0$ and also the other way: when $B^+A^+=0$ then $AB=0$. Where $B^+$ and $A^+$ are Moore-Penrose Pseudo-inverse of B and A.

Comment: Do the stars mean conjugate transpose?

Comment: No, multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\text{Let} \space A = U_1\Sigma_1V_1^* \space \text{and} \space B = U_2\Sigma_2V_2^* \space \text{(SVD of $A$ and $B$)} \\
\text{Then} \space A^+ = V_1\Sigma_1^+U_1^* \space \text{and} \space B^+ = V_2\Sigma_2^+U_2^* \\
$$

---

$$
\text{Now} \space AB = 0 \\
U_1\Sigma_1V_1^*U_2\Sigma_2V_2^* = 0\\
U_1^*U_1\Sigma_1V_1^*U_2\Sigma_2V_2^*V_2 = 0\\
\Sigma_1V_1^*U_2\Sigma_2 = 0 \\
\Sigma_1^+\Sigma_1^+\Sigma_1V_1^*U_2\Sigma_2\Sigma_2^+\Sigma_2^+ = 0 \\
\Sigma_1^+V_1^*U_2\Sigma_2^+ = 0 \\
\left(\Sigma_1^+V_1^*U_2\Sigma_2^+\right)^* = 0 \\
\Sigma_2^+U_2^*V_1\Sigma_1^+ = 0 \\
V_2\Sigma_2^+U_2^*V_1\Sigma_2^+U_1^* = 0 \\
B^+A^+ = 0
$$
You can show the converse by using the above proof and the fact that $\left(P^+\right)^+= P$ for any matrix $P$.

Comment: Can you explain a little more, what is SVD? And the star means transpose?

Comment: SVD means singular value decomposition and star means conjugate transpose.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
& AB = 0 \\
\Longrightarrow & A^{+}ABB^{+} = 0\\
\Longrightarrow & ((A^{+}A)(BB^{+}))^{*} = (BB^{+})^{*}(A^{+}A)^{*} = BB^{+}A^{+}A  = 0 & \texttt{(1)}\\
\Longrightarrow & B^{+}BB^{+}A^{+}AA^{+} = B^{+}A^{+} = 0 & \texttt{(2)}. 
\end{align}
$$ 
We have used $BB^{+}$ and $A^{+}A$ are Hermitian in $\texttt{(1)}$ and $B^{+}BB^{+} = B^{+}$ and $A^{+}AA^{+} = A^{+}$ in $\texttt{(2)}$ .

If $B^+A^+=0$ then from the previous result $(A^+)^+(B^+)^+ = A B = 0.$